# cut and copy files lost

Tags: data-recovery, overheating

I'm running 14.04

I was recently copy and pasting files from one external HD to another. My laptop has been overheating lately and shutting down.  Not thinking it happened again whilst transferring data. I believe I was moving about 350 gb only 130 or so was moved. The root files I copied from the original HD are now gone. Is there away to recover the rest of the data?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! First of all **do not touch the source drive anymore, until we fix the issue.** Was the external drive formatted as NTFS, exFAT or some other file system?